# FreeBSD tacacs+ client

Tags: security, authentication, authorization, freebsd

i've been trying to run a tacacs+ client on FreeBSD 9.2 but it doesn't work. the server is on windows using tacacs.net. i know the server is working because i can make the client work on a cisco router. but i can't get it to work on FreeBSD.

this is my /etc/pam.d/tacacs file:

```
auth        sufficient    /usr/lib/pam_tacplus.so     debug    server = 10.0.0.9    secret=somesecret
account     sufficient    /usr/lib/pam_tacplus.so     debug    server = 10.0.0.9    secret=somesecret    protocol=login
session     sufficient    /usr/lib/pam_tacplus.so     debug    server = 10.0.0.9    secret=somesecret    protocol=login
```

and /etc/pam.d/login:

```
auth        include        tacacs
account        include        tacacs
session        include        tacacs
```

and /etc/tacplus.conf:

```
10.0.0.9        "somesecret"        15
```

the problem is that there aren't any good tutorials on how to do this and all i did was based on some forums and i'm not sure if they are correct or not.

would be thankful if you could help me.
thanks,

EDIT: I've turned off my firewall on windows and now it connects. But now when i try to login, it prompts me for password for about 5 times and then it says "login incorrect. But the password is correct.

EDIT2: I've found that it authenticates correctly and FreeBSD gets it, but still doesn't login. my guess is that "login" service is looking somewhere else for login information and can't find TACACS+ users. i've read the login.conf file and haven't yet been able to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out how to make it work. after all these configuration, you'll need to add the TACACS+ user that you want to login with,locally on the client system. for example you have a bunch of users on the TACACS+ server, and now you want to login on the client with user "one". you'll need to add this user locally, without any further configuration, and you'll be set.
the problem is, you can't know all the users there is on the TACACS+ server; so i'm still looking for a better way.

**UPDATE**
the better way is to use pam_exec.so. you can write a script that adds the user to system; and have pam_exec execute it.